# How to configure Nginx to hide redirect URL of proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, location, proxypass

I have temporary url like `https://some.domain.com/o/21c8a618-b527`. Location /o/ took from "backend" another path like "/content/360.mp4". It took "/content/360.mp4" from http://another.com and browser start to play video. This part of configuration work correct.
When it opened temporary link I see new URL in browser like "http://another.com/content/360.mp4".
Could you please help me to solve issue? How can I configure Nginx to keep temporary URL `https://some.domain.com/o/21c8a618-b527` in client browser?

It's "some.domain.com" Nginx config file.

```
upstream backend {
    server backend;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/ssl;
    server_name some.domain.com;

    location /o/ {
        rewrite /v/(.+) /$1 break;
        uwsgi_pass backend;
        include uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /content/ {
        proxy_pass http://another.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a solution for this?